# How to rearrange EVA fields in profile2?

Tags: users

I augmented a profile2 profile with two Eva views.

Now, I would like to re-arrange them. For that, I would like to see those fields in the Manage display tab. I tried to explicitly create those missing fields, looking in vain for an Eva view type.

Anyone having met this problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Profile2(7.x-1.3) and Entity Views Attachment(7.x-1.2) on Drupal 7.34.

When you create two eva fields in your respective views and set "Entity type" as Profile and Bundle as "Your profile name" as shown in the following figures: Entity Type - Profile, Bundle - Custom. "Custom" is the name of the profile I created.

[image: View 1 with Eva Field Settings]

[image: View 2 with Eva Field Settings]

After saving the views with their respective eva fields , the fields for display automatically appear in the "Manage Display" tab of your profile as shown below(note the fields with prefix EVA) :

[image]

Here you can reorder EVA fields with ease.

And this is how the views are rendered in the user's profile page :

[image]

I included above screenshots, in case you have missed some settings. If you still can't see the required fields, then create a new issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/eva?categories=All) for EVA or [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/profile2?categories=All) for Profile2. Hope I could be of help. Please excuse me for my late reply as I am new to Drupal.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Ssd. Although I now work on other projects, I greatly appreciate :-)

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help